# xslt finding position of a specific element in a variable

Tags: variables, xslt, position

I have a global variable `name="cats" as="element()*`. The data I used to create the variable and the data I want to transform are in different parts of the tree of the document.
Let's say the variable contains the elements CellA, CellF and CellC (enclosed in `<Item>` tags).

My goal is to fill the following predefined structure with data from a table which contains as many cells `<field>` per `<line>` as the variable (and in the same order).

```
<row>
    <CellA> </CellA>
    <CellB> </CellB>
    <CellC> </CellC>
    <CellD> </CellD>
    <CellE> </CellE>
    <CellF> </CellF>
</row>
```

My idea is to check for each `<Cell_>` if the name exists in the variable and use its position to access the original data.
Unfortunately, I cannot use `position()` while looping through `$cats` because I am not able to access `<field>` here.

Another method, which was suggested elsewhere, would be to count the number of preceding-siblings where `$cats = Cell_`. However, the suggestion was not based on variables. And (due to being a novice) I was not able to figure out how to do this.
Is it possible to do it this way? Is there another way to do it?

If something is not clear, please let me know.

**Additional information**

*sourceXML*

```
<body>
    <line>
        <field>data</field>
        <field/>
        <field/>
    </line>
    <line/>
    ...
</body>
```

*targetXML* (see above)

*XSLT*

```
<xsl:variable name="cats" as="element()*">
    <Item>CellA</Item>
    <Item>CellF</Item>
    <Item>CellC</Item>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="body/line">
    <row>
        <CellA>
            *What to do here to fill it with data from source xml*
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="???"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="field[$pos]"/>
        </CellA>
        <CellB>
        </CellB>
        ...
    </row>
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve], please? I believe you should use the `index-of()` function, but it's hard to tell how exactly.

Comment: I would give an example if you had not already solved the problem. Thank you very much. I did not know about index-of() but it works as intended. (Would you like to post it as an answer for me to choose?)

Comment: I did, but without context it's not going to help anyone else reading this.

Comment: Please post the code necessary to understand why using `index-of` is the solution. Otherwise, this question will be closed. _"If something is not clear, please let me know."_ - you were told exactly that, so please do something about it.

Comment: I tried to simplify my code and translate it. Please ask for even more information if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My idea is to check for each `<Cell_>` if the name exists in the
>   variable and use its position to access the original data.

Apparently you want to use the `index-of()` function.